# Type 'User' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Tags: swift4, codable, hashable

```
class User: Mappable, CustomStringConvertible, Hashable{

    static func == (lhs: WUser, rhs: WUser) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name 
    }
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    .
    .
  }
```

Where Mappable is

```
protocol Mappable: Codable {
    init?(jsonData: Data?)
    init?(jsonString: String)
}
```

But it Says, **Type 'User' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember when you conform your type to a `protocol`, you need to implement the required entities(properties, methods) of that `protocol`. For example, Hashable has the required method `hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)` so you need to implement that as below,

```
class WUser: Mappable, CustomStringConvertible, Hashable {

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.name)
        hasher.combine(self.email)
    }

    required init?(jsonData: Data?) {

    }

    required init?(jsonString: String) {

    }

    var description: String {
        return self.name ?? ""
    }

    static func == (lhs: WUser, rhs: WUser) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
}
```

Above code has no compiling issues as i have implemented all the requirements for each `protocol` (i.e, `Mappable`, `CustomStringConvertible`, `Hashable`)